# nuxt builder in nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, builder, nuxtjs3

Nuxt 2 was having builder which we used to build nuxt app.

But nuxt 3 is not having builder. Is that not part of nuxt 3? Following is what we were using in nuxt 2.

`import { Builder } from '@nuxt/builder';`

I am serving nuxt app from nestjs like following example of next.js.

`https://github.com/hnviradiya/contact-list/blob/main/src/server/client-app/client-app.service.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is equivalent to Nuxt 2 code.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module.js';
import { loadNuxt } from 'nuxt3';
import { buildNuxt,  Resolver } from '@nuxt/kit';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Check if we need to run Nuxt in development mode
  const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

  // Get a ready to use Nuxt instance
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt({ rootDir: 'src/client-app/' })

  // Enable live build & reloading on dev
  if (isDev) {
    buildNuxt(nuxt)
  }

  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```