# Run Nuxt 3 programmatically

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to run Nuxt 3 programmatically. This is what I got so far:

```ts
import { loadNuxt, build } from 'nuxt';

const options = {
    rootDir: '../nuxt.config.ts',
    dev: false,
};

async function main(){
    const nuxt = await loadNuxt(options);
    await build(nuxt);
}

main();
```

And this is what I get in the logs:

```
ℹ Client built in 897ms
ℹ Building server...
✔ Server built in 922ms
✔ Generated public .output/public
ℹ Initializing prerenderer
ℹ Prerendering 3 routes
  ├─ / (6ms) 
  ├─ /200 (0ms) 
  ├─ /404 (1ms) 
start Building server...
start Writing server bundle...
✔ Server built
  ├─ .output/server/package.json (307 B) (183 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/index.mjs (458 B) (257 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs.map (58.1 kB) (4.44 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs (18.7 kB) (5.74 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs.map (15.5 kB) (2.73 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs (11.8 kB) (3.83 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs.map (2.77 kB) (505 B gzip)
  └─ .output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs (3.8 kB) (651 B gzip)
Σ Total size: 651 kB (150 kB gzip)
✔ You can preview this build using node .output/server/index.mjs
```

So it seems to me that is building and generating the files.
When I run:

```
node .output/server/index.mjs
```

The server is loading but it is broken, it cannot find what it seems the main js file:

```
GET http://locahost:3000/_nuxt/entry.a5f4ac90.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Cannot find static asset /_nuxt/entry.a5f4ac90.mjs)
```

I was able to run Nuxt 2 programmatically with no problem, I am wondering if it is possible also for Nuxt 3.

#### Edit

Something I figured out is that the `nuxt.config.ts` must have `ssr: true`.

This is my `nuxt.config.ts` now:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
        srcDir: './src/nuxt',
        target: 'static',
        typescript: {
                typeCheck: false
        },
        buildDir: './.nuxt',
        components: [
                {
                        path: '~/components/',
                        extensions: ['vue']
                }
        ],
        generate: {
                dir: './dist/admin',
                fallback: '404.html',
                subFolders: false,
                exclude: ['/urn-admin'],
        }
})
```

```
// my page directory structure
pages/
- index.vue
- about.vue
```

And now I am getting this error:

```
GET http://locahost:3000/_nuxt/entry.c132761b.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Cannot find static asset /_nuxt/entry.c132761b.mjs)
GET http://locahost:3000/_nuxt/index.50f3e684.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Cannot find static asset /_nuxt/index.50f3e684.mjs)
GET http://locahost:3000/_nuxt/about.2286c269.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Cannot find static asset /_nuxt/about.2286c269.mjs)
GET http://locahost:3000/_nuxt/error-component.17941a7e.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Cannot find static asset /_nuxt/error-component.17941a7e.mjs)
```

It should be good to have a documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using [@nuxt/kit](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/kit/) for this purpose as nuxt 3 is not providing the same way as nuxt 2 in this matter. And i think your code may have compatibility issues with nuxt 3. Also, try checking [nuxt 3 documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org) to create the `nuxt.config.ts` file the proper way, as your config file may have issues with nuxt 3. As you are overriding `buildDir` and `Generate directory`, In normal situations, this error would be a sign of different 'buildDir' and 'PublicPathDir'.

By the way, the following may help you bypass these errors but won't solve the possible root causes.

1. Try running `npm cache clean --force` or `npx nuxi clean` before building. Your error may be the consequence of changing publicPathDir or other hard coded directories at the runtime. this will clean the cache and rule out this possible cause.
2. Try your code in development mode and if the problem resolved, try using something like the following in your `nuxt.config.js` after installing `@nuxtjs/proxy`:

`modules:[['@nuxtjs/proxy',{"/_nuxt/":{target:'http://localhost:3000/_nuxt'}}]]`

3. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468921/nuxt-builder-in-nuxt3) may be helpful as it's similar to the way you seek to use nuxt 3.